# Best way to check if your VM is running

Tags: php

## Browser

VM ip = **172.16.67.137**

I goto : http://172.16.67.137:1234/vse/accounts.count on my local brower

I got this response

```
Object
data:Object
account_count:20
message:"Success"
status:200
```

---

## Terminal

But how comes when I tried ping that URL

- `ping http://172.16.67.137:1234`
- `ping http://172.16.67.137`

All of them return me

> ping: cannot resolve http://172.16.67.137:1234/vse/accounts.count: Unknown host

---

Did I do something wrong or missing any steps ?

I just want to check if my VMs is running before do any other action, otherwise, throw some errors.

Hope someone can shed some lights on this ...

Comment: Try just pinging the IP no port either

Comment: That is the same too.

Comment: ping works on ip's. you cannot use it to ping a url.

Comment: You're right. It works like charm now. Stupid me. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping only works with url's not uri's or ports.
When I say URL I mean with out http://

You would have to do this:

```
ping 172.16.67.137
```

Ping does not work with ports

You could use telnet to check it.

`telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like it.

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Mac.  Terminal Application.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal run `curl` to get the response

```
curl http://172.16.67.137:1234/vse/accounts.count
```